# NO_PUBKEY "4EB27DB2A3B88B8B" for Dart apt repo

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, apt, dart

A while ago I installed the Dart SDK using [apt-get](https://dart.dev/get-dart#install-using-apt-get), but I noticed recently that `apt update` was showing an error `NO_PUBKEY "4EB27DB2A3B88B8B"` and I was unable to update Dart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: and this just happened again: `NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2`
The fix below still works to clear the issue.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like a key had expired.

This Linux Mint Forum post [mintUpdate NO_PUBKEY for Google Earth repository](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=377870) suggested running:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

and that did cure the problem for me when running `apt update` again :)

Answer (score 5):

Since the use of apt-key is deprecated, except for the use of apt-key del in maintainer scripts to remove existing keys from the main keyring (according to the man page)

You can use the following:

```bash
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub |
    gpg --dearmor - |
    sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google-linux-key.gpg >/dev/null
```

Comment: Doesn't the sudo there need to be before `gpg` rather than `wget`?

Comment: Yeap you are right. edit

Comment: https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ has Google's prose for this

Answer (score 3):

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys  THE_MISSING_KEY_HERE

worked already 2 times for me

found it when I had    no pub key  etc

Comment: Right after installing LM21 i installed Google Earth again. After running sudo apt update